# Docker COPY */*.*

Tags: docker, dockerfile, copy

Нужно скопировать файлы по директориям в контейнере. Пытаюсь COPY /srcs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf выходит ошибка COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder598404233/srcs/nginx.conf: no such file or directory, а если я копирую папку целкиком - то все работает, как мне сделать адресацию?

Comment: Проверьте путь. Обычно папка называется src, а не srcs.

Comment: Еще исходный файл у тебя начинается со слэша `/srcs/...` - у докера есть ограничение, что нельзя копировать файлы/папки, которые находятся за пределами папки, в которой находится Dockerfile. Попробуй `COPY srcs/ngninx.conf`